# Migrate Dimensions

Tags: migrations

I am trying to migrate to a physical dimensions field with no success. I will prepare the data in prepareRow but before that I was just trying to figure out how it should work. I tried setting default values like this:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_productdimensions')->defaultValue(4);
$this->addFieldMapping('field_productdimensions:width')->defaultValue(1);
$this->addFieldMapping('field_productdimensions:length')->defaultValue(2);
$this->addFieldMapping('field_productdimensions:height')->defaultValue(3);
$this->addFieldMapping('field_productdimensions:unit','cm');
```

The above did not insert any data. I also tried with values in prepareRow like this:

```
    $current_row->dimensions = array(
      'length' => 1,
      'width' => 2,
      'height' => 3,
      'unit' => 'cm'
    );
```

All other fields are inserted properly. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, although it seems weird that width gets the length value, this is how it works in my case. Nothing else was needed in prepareRow function.

```
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_productdimensions','width');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_productdimensions:width','length')->defaultValue(null);
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_productdimensions:length','length')->defaultValue(null);
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_productdimensions:height','height')->defaultValue(null);
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_productdimensions:unit','length_units');
```

Answer (score 0):

As I struggeled with this issue today, you actually need to leave out the length mapping, otherwise your migration will fail and all your fields will be empty.

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_productdimensions','length')->defaultValue(null);
$this->addFieldMapping('field_productdimensions:width','width')->defaultValue(null);
$this->addFieldMapping('field_productdimensions:height','height')->defaultValue(null);
$this->addFieldMapping('field_productdimensions:unit','length_units')->defaultValue('mm');
```

Also note that the value you try to put in is strictly an integer. A value with a space behind it will not work.